# Create hierarchical school clusters

Tags: clustering

I have a CSV containing UK County data for schools.

For each school I have it's location, name, size (number of pupils), and phase (primary/secondary/tertiary).

I am trying to cluster the schools - associating the many smaller primary schools with the nearest secondary school.

The obvious tools don't seem intended for this use as they always leave outliers/'noise'.

I want every school to be in a cluster - ideally in a polygon on the map to visualise which cluster they are in (I don't know if a convex hull can be incorporated to minimise the spatial spread - I suspect this would be quite complex).

I don't have much experience with GIS but can use either QGIS or ArcGIS Pro to achieve the outcome.  I can also use R if that would provide a solution?

Comment: It may well be what I'm trying to do isn't clustering - but grouping?

Comment: You could try some processing tool like "Distance to nearest hub" or "Join attributes by nearest" (or "Join attributes by nearest with condition" if you install the "ProcessX" plugin) all three should let you attribute the nearest secondary school to each primary school (you may need to split you original layer between primary and secondary)

Comment: Voronoi (Thiessen) polygons around around all points.  For each primary school dissolve secondary school polygons that touch primary school polygon?  Repeat for next primary school?